# Como adicionar propriedades em um ExpandoObject()?

Tags: c#

Eu estava usando o tipo *dynamic* e fui alertado que ele tem problema de performance.

Como eu poderia fazer o código abaixo usando `ExpandoObject` ?

```
 dynamic dObject = new ExpandoObject();
 dObject.a= a;
```

E como eu conseguiria ordenar uma lista de `ExpandoObject` ?

Com uma lista de *dynamic* eu posso fazer isso:

```
dList.OrderBy(minhalista => minhalista.a).ToArray();
```

Mas com *Expand* eu não consigo.

Answer (score 1):

`ExpandoObject` é do "tipo" `dynamic`.

Então, você deve usar deste jeito mesmo.

```
dynamic dObject = new ExpandoObject();
dObject.A = new ExpandoObject();
dObject.A.Nome = "Paulo";
```

Comment: Mas ao fazer dynamic dObject = new ExpandoObject(); eu nao estou usando o "tipo" dynamic?

Comment: Acho que você tá confundindo as coisas, `ExpandoObject` é `dynamic`

Comment: Como assim? é um ALIAS?